# combining several tables to a table of structures

Tags: matlab

Say I have several tables with the same variables and the same size. How I combine them together to have a table of structures, when each structure contains several variables from the different tables?

```
%input
a = table([1; 1], [2; 2]);
b = table(['c'; 'c'], ['d'; 'd']);
%output
ab = table([struct('a', 1, 'b', 'c'); struct('a', 1, 'b', 'c')], ...
    [struct('a', 2, 'b', 'd'); struct('a', 2, 'b', 'd')]);
```

I am looking for an elegant way, not for a wordy code.

Comment: what do you mean by "a table of structures"? could you show a small example for explaining your question and desired output?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would use nested `table`s (rather than `struct` inside `table`), and use [`inner2outer`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.inner2outer.html) like this:

```
>> inner2outer(table(a,b))
ans =
  2×2 table
     Var1      Var2 
    a    b    a    b
    ______    ______
    1    c    2    d
    1    c    2    d
```